# How to concatenate text files(or .con files) into one file?

Tags: python

I am having a problem with concatenating multiple files into one. When I tried doing this one file, it worked. However with two files, it did not create a new file where it merges both files. I tried everything from `glob.glob` and `os.path.join` however I keep getting same errors with syntax or list attribute has no object replace.

```py
import glob
import os
import os.path

read_files_2=['NYASv1.con', '20Rev1.con','Nv1.con',
              'L1v1.con','fig_L1v1.con','R_L1v1.con']

read_files = glob.glob("I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Sing\%s.con",% read_files_2)

with open("result.con", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I get syntax errors with `%s.con",% read_files_2`

Comment: You should iterate over your `read_files_2` list. `glob.glob` matches a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If all files are in the same folder, simply iterate through them using [`path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```py
import os

dr = "I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Sing"
read_files = [os.path.join(dr, f) for f in read_files_2]
```

Rest of the code is the same as yours

2. If they are not, use the top-most level directory including all of them and use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.walk):

```py
import os

dr = "I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Sing"
read_files = []
for root, _, files in os.walk(dr):
    for file in files:
        if file in read_files_2:
            read_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

If you still want to use `glob`, you could use `iglob` which is the iterator version:

```py
import glob

dr = "I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Sing\**\*.con"
read_files = []
for file in glob.iglob(dr, recursive=True):
    if file in read_files_2:
        read_files.append(file)
```

Comment: If they are not in the same folser, how would i adjust code: let's say i have two in one folder and two in another

Comment: Well depends on what you have to work with... Do you know which folders?

Comment: `I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Mult`

Comment: `read_files.append(os.path.join(root, f))
NameError: name 'f' is not defined` im getting this error

Comment: When I changed `f` to `_`, I get this error:                                              `result_path = result_path + p_path TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Comment: I fixed it. simply change `f` to `file`. kinda obvious from the context

Comment: Thank you @Tomerikoo . I had one more question: im trying to figure out the `_` you put in the for loop, why is that there?

Comment: @joe oh yes, that is just a way to tell python you're not interested in some variable. for example, the function we're using, `walk`, returns a 3-tuple (root, subfolders, files). We are only interested in `root` and `files` and don't use `subfolders` so simply put `_` instead. read [here](https://www.pythonmania.net/en/2017/03/05/underscore-in-python/) section 4 for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a syntax error is that you have the cluster `,%`, which is invalid. The comma implies what comes after is another argument, and `%` is not a valid beginning of an expression. I think you are thinking of `"... %s ..." % read_files_2`. But that still would not work the way you intend.

I think what you are intending to do is either

1. `glob.glob('I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Sing\*.con')`
2. `['I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg\Sing\%s.con' % file for file in read_files_2]`

Glob looks for every file matching a pattern, and the other matches only things formatted that way.

If you want all `.con` files under `I:\T\FE19\Cont\Traes\ctg`, you could use

```
glob.glob('I:\\T\\FE19\\Cont\\Traes\\ctg\\**\\*.con', recursive=True)
```

Which finds all files with the `*.con` extension under that directory.